# How can I view just the tweets of my followers?

Tags: twitter

What if I'm trying to do relationship development and I care more about the people I have a reciprocal relationship on Twitter?

I know there are many bulk-unfollow tools, but that only makes sense when I have given up on a user and don't think I'll ever be able to develop a two way relationship with them.

The default news stream displays people I aspire to network with mixed in with people who follow me. With a 20% follow back rate, that means 80% of my stream is lower-priority content from people who I have a one side relationship with.

I considered lists, but that is a maintenance nightmare & doesn't allow for suppressing retweets.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The request for an alternate client is off-topic here, but if you don't get a reply on how to do it via the regular client, you can flag this to be moved over to [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: I'll edit & see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I manage this way.  For the folks whose tweets I always want to see, I created a list (mine titled "favorites"; yours might be "important", etc).  So, I try and keep that list short and then can check it frequently. The rest of the folks I check on when convenient.
And it's pretty easy to move folks on and off your VIP list as situations change.